# display jquery confirmation dialog center of screen

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I would like to display the Confirmation on center of screen.
My View:

```
<table id="test" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Value</th>
                <th>Message</th>
                <th>EffectiveDate</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.LookupValues)
            {            
                <tr>

                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Value)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Message)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.EffectiveDate)</td>
                    <td>
                       @Html.ActionLink("DeleteTEST", "Delete", "Values", new { area = "Admin", id = item.LookupValueKey }, new { @class = "deleteTEST" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.deleteTEST').click(function () {
        var answer = confirm('Do you want to delete this record?');
        if (answer) {
            $.post(this.href, function () {
                window.location.reload(); //Callback
            });
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Which displays on top of screen.

Can anyone tell how to display this confirmation on center.

Comment: Where is the jQuery Dialog you are talking about? All I can see is the plain Javascript confirm.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't position the default dialog boxes.

You probably want to use the jQuery UI dialog. [Details and example is here](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position).